# Magento : Displaying Pop Up Onclick Add to Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart, popup

when we upload image in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) and click on "**Add to cart**", its Adding product to cart successfully, but when we **click on "add to cart" directly** without uploading an image , it displaying pop up box & displaying message "Add text or image".

I want to **Hide the pop up box when we click on "Add to cart" directly**.

I need similar to this link : [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5.html)

**addtocart.phtml**

```
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" id="submit-editorApply-add-to-cart" >
Add to cart
</button>
```

**script** :

```
<script>

initObservers: function() 
{ 
if (this.config.editorEnabled && this.config.isUserLoggedIn == 'true') { 
$('submit-editorApply-add-to-cart').observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
} 
}, 

submitApply: function(event) 
{ 
Event.stop(event); 
this.option.apply(); 
if(window.productAddToCartForm == 'undefined') { 
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form'); 
} else { 
var productAddToCartForm = window.productAddToCartForm; 
} 
productAddToCartForm.submit(); 

},
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Cant click on add to cart even after adding image. It still shows "upload image or text."

Comment: @KingshukDeb can you please recheck [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , its working for me......

Comment: @KingshukDeb sorry, we need to login to check that, can you please login with demo credentials : `kidsdial11@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial11`

Comment: What do you mean? login where?

Comment: @KingshukDeb please   login here : [login link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/customer/account/login) or once you click on `save design` in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , it will show options to login....

Comment: very simple. Open the product page. Open inspect element. Find for `product-custom-option`. You will find 2 occurrence. You need the second one which is a hidden input field and class is `input-text aitcg-required product-custom-option`. Remove  `aitcg-required` from that class.

Comment: @KingshukDeb seems i removed corect `aitcg-required` , but now its not displaying any `pop up` but its not showing any validation message as before  once we click on `add to cart` directly....

Comment: Which validation message?

Comment: @KingshukDeb please check [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5.html) and if you click on `add to cart` directly it showing validation message as `upload image or text` , i want to show that message, once i removed `aitcg-required` , that also not displaying......

Comment: Do one thing. After clicking `add to cart` show the message using javascript and then again remove it and then you can add the product to cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56725/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-kingshuk-deb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have just added a frontend validation for this. The class name is `input-text aitcg-required product-custom-option` . If you remove this `aitcg-required` part from class name you will be able to add products to cart.